# Asking to be moved to an office out of a cubicle

Tags: work-environment, company-culture

How can I go about asking my boss to be moved to an office that just became available. For the past 8 years I’ve been working out of a cubicle. I’ve been with the company those years and have moved progressively to higher positions.

Should I do it by email what should I say?

Answer (score 11):

> How can I go about asking my boss to be moved to an office that just
>   became available?

Just ask.

Something like "Hey boss. That office just became available. What's the chance that I could get it? I've been working out of a cubicle for the past 8 years." should be a good start.

> Should I do it by email what should I say?

Do it in person.

Answer (score 4):

Getting a cubicle is partly about seniority and position, but also about practical purposes. Do you have a lot of meetings, phone calls, client interactions, confidential conversations? If not, you may not get this office. The best approach for you is to lay out to your manager, face to face if possible, why it is in the interest of the company for you to have this office over other employees. Get your manager's agreement first, and if you cannot, then drop the request.

Comment: ... but it's *mostly* about seniority.